# Retornando o total com a data numa consulta com o SUM

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Estou precisando retornar uma soma do campo value da tabela m e junto com ela a data do campo inicial do campo `sale_date`, sendo que está apresentando erro de  aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
    sum(m.value),
    t.sale_date 
from t_transaction t 
left join t_movement m on m.transaction_id =  t.id 
where t.paybox_id = 26
```

Precisaria retornar o total acompanhado da data. A data é a mesma para todos os registros...

Obs.: sem o `t.sale_date` retorna o total do value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os campos que não estão nas funções de agregação, devem ser informados no `Group By`, no seu caso o `t.sale_date`. Sem esse campo, funciona porque não há outros além do que está na função `sum()`.

```
SELECT 
    sum(m.value), 
    t.sale_date 
from t_transaction t 
left join t_movement m on m.transaction_id = t.id 
where t.paybox_id = 26
group by t.sale_date
```

Documentação da sintaxe do Select: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html

Comment: Então, fiz este processo antes, mas deixo de totalizar os valores...
O que desejo do id 26:
value /  sale_date
364.54 / 2018-01-08 12:07:43.68

Comment: então o sale_date não é igual para os movimentos. Coloque a sua estrutura de tabelas e uma amostra de dados que tem nelas por favor, além de um exemplo de como quer a saída dos dados @aleestevao

Comment: Rovann, resolvi o problema criando duas queries mesmo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que entendi o que quer:

```
SELECT 
    sum(m.value), 
    MIN(t.sale_date) 
from t_transaction t 
left join t_movement m on m.transaction_id = t.id 
where t.paybox_id = 26
```

É isto mesmo ?

Comment: Resolvi a questão utilizando duas queries. Obrigado!